# Limiting Access to a subdirectory, httpd.conf access is not allowed, don't want to create htaccess apart from root directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web-applications

I researched for this quite a long time, but could not find proper answer. 
I am using Free PHP Hosting website which is provided by `000webhost.com`. 
I have a `.htaccess` in public_html folder given by them. 
directory structure has sub-directory such as `includes` which I dont want the users to if they directly go to URL, It should say `Forbidden - 403`.

I do not want `.htaccess` in every sub-directory where I do not want allow access. 
I read somewhere that .htaccess can change behavior of all the subdirectories and itself.

I know performance wise it is not a good option, but I do not have access to httpd.conf.

I think on SO there are some answers which tells me this :
 1. move those subdirectories outsides the public_html (do not want to do that)
 2. create `.htaccess` for every subdirectories and denying access (which is pain and not a scalable solution)
 3. Use rewrite rules (Could be a solution not sure)
I hope someone can understand and help me out.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is wrong with adding .htaccess is a few subdirectories?
You only need to do it at the the top directories. How many are there really?

Comment: There are all in all I think 4 forbidden directories. I dont want 4 `.htaccess` files it will make my life miserable, I think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, the most secure solution is to move those directories outside the DocumentRoot. However, you can easily add rewrite rules in your one .htaccess to forbid access:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Group many forbidden directories as (a|b|c|d)
RewriteRule ^(include|otherforbidden|someotherone) - [F]
```

Unless you have dozens of directories downstream to manage though, I don't see a big problem with dropping a directory-specific .htaccess in each.

Comment: It is just that, like web.xml in java world you have one or two files to control behavior and see what is happening, which makes managing easier and less time consuming. Thanks a lot Michael, I will try this.

Comment: can you tell me what F stands for is that Forbidden?

Comment: F is Forbidden.  See the flags section in [the RewriteRule documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Answer (score 1):

add `RedirectMatch 403 ^/includes/.*$` to your root `.htaccess` file to redirect any calls to the /includes directory to force a **403 Forbidden** error.

However, it would be safer to use `RedirectMatch 404 ^/includes/.*$` instead because attackers will get a **404 File Not Found** error instead.  This is considered safer because the 403 error let's attackers know that there is a file to attack.

Comment: good thinking Jeff. I got the part, it will not tell it, whether the folder actually exists or not. thanks

Comment: I am sorry jeff.. but I can only select one answer as approved one..I could have done yours but...